# Extend class with instance function

Tags: jquery, class

http://jsfiddle.net/hzC78/7/

```
var ArrayExtension = {
    foo: function(){
        return "bar"
    }
}

$.extend(Array, ArrayExtension);

var array = ['zero','one','two'];

console.log('From class: ' + ArrayExtension.foo() ); // bar
console.log('From extended original class: ' + Array.foo() ); // bar
console.log('From instance of original class: ' + array.foo() ); // undefined is not a function, expected 'bar'
```

**Update:**

The `extend` method appears to work. `Array` now includes the foo attribute that runs the anonymous function that returns `bar`...

But why then does an instance of `Array`, `array`, contain no such attribute?

Comment: What you expecting us to do with just your codes

Comment: @Igor useless comment. Also wrong

Comment: @Igor And now deleting your wrong comments! Have you no honour, sir?

Comment: I am just trying to learn.

Comment: @Igor Well if you're an ESL speaker I'm just letting you know your comments came off as a bit sarcastic. Apologies for any miscommunication...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are extending `Array` istself and not the array prototype.

This will work:

```
$.extend(Array.prototype, ArrayExtension);
```

In JavaScript objects are created after their prototypes. An array instance gets all methods from the array prototype. If you want every array instance to have your foo method you will have to extend the array prototype, not the array object.

[Here's a jsfiddle to illustrate this.](http://jsfiddle.net/9kBA3/6/)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to work? haha http://jsfiddle.net/9kBA3/2/ If you look in the console, `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Yes, because now the prototype is extended. So you can't call `Array.foo()`any longer. That's a big diffrence

Comment: Array.foo() is like a class/static method. But in my code you define a "normal" method. Like in any other language you can't call a method on the  class itself.

Comment: Yep, I see now. It's a little bit different to Ruby, thanks for your help